# Can one formalize the difficulty of proofs?

Tags: soft-question

My question is if there is any specific possibility to make consistent valuations of how difficult a specific mathematical argument/proof is? Starting with elementary proofs as being set "trivial" - would it be possible to "measure" how much creativity resp. interplay of different concepts a proof needs, and to condense long computations with just manipulations as elementary?

I came along this question when I thought about the fact that people often use different phrases for math proofs, like "totally obvious", "rather obvious", "obvious", "not completely obvious", "this is not so trivial", "highly non-trivial", etc. So it seems to me that there is sort of a feeling and concept as what is difficult or not - is it possible fo formalize this rigorously and consistently? Maybe with giving every proof a number on how difficult it is in the end?

Please help me with the tags for this question if you think there is a better choice; I will remove this comment afterwards.

Comment: Related: ["When is something 'obvious'?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151782/409)  (The question isn't about *measuring* the (non-)obviousness of a proof, *per se*, so may not count as a duplicate. That said, since (non-)obviousness is inherently subjective, measuring is a rather problematic task.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you, but I would say my questions goes rather in a different direction: is it possible to make it a rather not subjective question by "measuring" the amount of new ideas involved in an argument. Of course, how hard a specific new idea is to come by - I  accept now - is subjective.

Comment: @Blue May I refer to an older question of mine? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612110/arguments-proofs-as-elements I would say this question is kind of related, as if there is a possibility to consider proofs as "elements" and then maybe really "value" or "measure" them as such?

Comment: Related: Wikipedia article titled [Proof complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_complexity) *AND* Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on Kurt Gödel, section [2.3 Speed-up Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#SpeUpThe) *AND* [Lengths of proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151852/13130) *AND* [Upper and Lower bounds on proof length](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71395/13130) *AND* [Deep theorems and long proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149115/15780) *AND* [Is there good reference for proof complexity?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280801/15780)